# Loop in R to read Files in multiple folders with no name pattern

Tags: r

I have folders for each day of each month, each containing 5-40 CSV files. The files have paths like

```
rootfolder/2/20/CSV/date-field-num.csv
```

and I want to read them all into R at once instead of individually. Is there a way to use a loop to do this if the files are in separate folders? The folder names have an obvious pattern. The actual CSV file names are of the form `date-field-num.csv`, where `field` could be anything and `num` could be any number.

Comment: Is `date` in `date-field-num` literally `date` or is it `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of the CSV files under `rootfolder`, then something like this should work:

```r
## Get character vector listing paths to CSV files
fn <- list.files("path/to/rootfolder", pattern = "[.]csv$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

## Construct list of data frames
l <- lapply(fn, read.csv, ...)
```

with `...` listing optional arguments to `read.csv`. Otherwise, you need to filter `fn` before the `lapply` call. Maybe:

```r
fn_full <- fn
fn <- grep("^rootfolder/\\d+/\\d+/CSV/date-[^-]+-\\d+[.]csv$", fn_full, value = TRUE)
```

I'd be somewhat worried about memory usage with ~1000 CSV files. You might need to process `fn` in batches.